# Is there a better way to redirect stdout in C++/CLI then with system()?

Tags: c++, c++-cli, stdout

In 2 parts of the C++/CLI code I'm working on, the program needs to run a different executable and have its STDOUT output redirected to a file. Its being attempted in 2 different ways, and only one of the 2 currently works. The program is being run on Windows XP.

The first section assembles a long char* that ends up looking something like this:

```
char* exepath = "start/B /D\\root\\bin \\root\\bin\\process.exe 1>\\root\\logs\\process_STDOUT.txt"
```

Then the code simply calls

```
Status = system(exepath);
```

This works fine: It both runs process.exe and creates the process_STDOUT.txt file as expected.

The second section tries to do the same using a ProcessStartInfo object instead. It successfully starts process.exe, but has not been creating the redirected output .txt file. Here is a simplified version of that code:

```
 Process p = gcnew Process();
 ProcessStartInfo^ s = gcnew ProcessStartInfo();
 s->FileName         = "\\root\\bin\\process.exe";
 s->WindowStyle      = ProcessWindowStyle::Hidden;
 s->CreateNoWindow   = true;
 s->UseShellExecute  = false;
 s->Arguments        = "1>\\root\\logs\\process_STDOUT.txt";
 p->StartInfo        = s;
 p->Start();
```

Am I doing something wrong with this code? And if not, is going back to just calling system(exepath) my only option or are there any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system` function invokes the system's command-line interpretter, which on Windows is usually *cmd.exe*. *That's* the program that parses the I/O-redirection syntax. The program you're starting has no idea what `>` means; it interprets that as the first character of an actual command-line argument. (Think about it — have *you* ever written command-line-redirection code in *your* command-line programs? No, of course not. Neither did the author of *process.exe*.)

So that's why your `ProcessStartInfo` method doesn't redirect I/O. For that, see the question here about [redirecting stdin and stdout in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788279/redirecting-stdin-and-stdout-in-net).

Since you're redirecting output to a file anyway, your current `system` code should be fine. The more programmatic ways of redirecting are necessary when you want to collect the output within your program instead of a file.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ProcessStartDemo.aspx) article. Noteworthy:

```
/* Setup Redirect */
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

/* Capture Output */
StreamWriter inputWriter = process.StandardInput;
StreamReader outputReader = process.StandardOutput;
StreamReader errorReader = process.StandardError;
process.WaitForExit();
```

Passing `"1>\\root\\logs\\process_STDOUT.txt"` as an argument is not the same as redirecting

Answer (score 0):

The "pipe command" is not passed as a parameter to the program; the shell interprets it and the program itself has no idea that its output is being redirected to a file. So you don't want to pass stuff like that as an argument.

However, the `Program` class has `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` stream properties to help you capture output. You simply need to specify (in your `ProcessStartInfo` object) that you want to redirect output.

```
s->RedirectStandardOutput = true;
s->RedirectStandardError = true;
```

Past that point, you'll be able to use [`p->StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [`p->StandardError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to get the output of the stream.