# How to interact with a process through stdout and stdin

Tags: .net, windows, process, f#

I'm trying start an F# interactive subprocess, send code to it through standard input, and receive the response through standard output.  Here is the code of my attempt (the command line args are just `fsi`, which is on the path"):

```
let readStrStream (stream : StreamReader) =
  let buffer = Array.create 1024 (char 0)
  let bytesReceived = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
  let chars = buffer |> Array.take bytesReceived
  let str = String.Concat(chars)
  str


let rec loop (proc : Process) = async {
  proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("printf \"iteration\"")

  let output = readStrStream proc.StandardOutput
  printfn "%s" output
  let error = readStrStream proc.StandardError
  printfn "%s" error
  return! loop proc }


let start proc =
  Async.Start(loop proc, cancellationToken = cts.Token)
  { new IDisposable with member x.Dispose() = cts.Cancel }


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let procStart = new ProcessStartInfo(argv.[0], argv.[1..] |> String.concat " ")
  procStart.UseShellExecute <- false
  procStart.RedirectStandardInput <- true
  procStart.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
  procStart.RedirectStandardError <- true
  procStart.WorkingDirectory <- "C:\\Users\\Philip"
  let proc = Process.Start(procStart)
  proc.StandardInput.AutoFlush <- true
  let x = start proc
  let y = Console.ReadLine()
  0
```

This code does not work.  When I run it, it just prints 2 newlines.

If I change the code like so,

```
let proc = Process.Start(procStart)
Thread.Sleep(10000)
```

The program prints out

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 14.0.23020.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

>
```

Which is the startup text of `fsi`.

I did some debugging, and here is what I found.
In the first code, both calls to `readStrStream` return `\r\n` on the first iteration, and on the second iteration, they first call hangs.

In the second code, the call returns the `fsi` output.

It seems to me that for some reason the stream is closing down after one call to `stream.Read`.

I've been playing with other things besides fsi, like python or irb, but they did not work either.

How do I fix this?

Comment: from memory old versions (and possibly new ones) used a weird event loop to read input that may have bypassed stdin.  what are you trying to do here anyway?

Comment: @JohnPalmer In this code here, I'm trying to send a line of code over and over.  I'm ultimately trying to make a sort of generalized repl.

Comment: I think you want https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service

Comment: @JohnPalmer Not quite. What I mean by generalized repl is that this program could be used as a python or ruby (or anything else) repl interface.  It's basically a frontend for multiple backends.  The project you mentioned even recommends using stdin and stdout in certain situations - http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix it, but I don't entirely understand all that is going on.
This answer helped me find the solution.
[Redirecting stdin and stdout in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788279/redirecting-stdin-and-stdout-in-net).

The trick is to use `proc.BeginOutputReadLine()` and then subscribe to `proc.OutputDataReceived` instead of calling readline.  I think the reason this works has something to do with it being asynchronous.