# Get STDOUT and STDERR messages from referenced C++ wrapper in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, stdout

I am using a .NET reference, which is a wrapper around a C++ unmanaged object in a .NET Framework project. Everything works fine, but I noticed when I am debugging in Visual Studio, in the Output window, there is a fair amount of logging that is clearly coming from the wrapped up, C++ unmanaged code. I assume this is because that C++ library is logging via STDOUT and STDERR and Visual Studio shows these logs in the Output window.

The question is, how can I get access to the logs from within my project? It seems if Visual Studio can get it and display it in the output window, I should be able to in code as well? I am envisioning I would need some kind of listener that can raise events when STDOUT or STDERR messages come in? I have been searching the web and can't seem to find anything that works.

The reason I want to do this is because I have my own logger, using Log4Net that I use in my application. When I am not debugging, I would like to still have these logs and I can write them using my Log4Net logger.

UPDATE: Others have suggested to use the `Process` for my current process. In my case, I am not manually starting the process but rather, just calling methods on the referenced .NET wrapper. So, I did try this:

```
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

process.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;
```

And then in the EventHandler `Process_OutputDataReceived` created above, I put a breakpoint. When I run this, I did confirm that the process variable contains my current process that I am debugging. However, I still see the message scrolling in the output window but the breakpoint of the event handler never fires. I guess this means that the unmanaged application is NOT using STDOUT unless I am still doing something wrong.

I should note that the unmanaged object is Tensorflow which is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow and the wrapper is by EMGU TF, which wraps Tensorflow so I can use it in .NET. Not sure if that spawns new thoughts. But, to summarize my issue, when I am debugging, there are tons of log lines in the output window from Tensorflow and I just want to gain access to those logs in my application.

EDIT 2: Here is an example of some of the lines that are in the output window of Visual Studio that I would like to capture so I can log them in my log4net file:

> 2022-01-11 13:31:35.811118: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
> to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical
> operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other operations, rebuild
> TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 2022-01-11
> 13:31:35.812270: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0
> with properties:  pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660
> computeCapability: 7.5 coreClock: 1.83GHz coreCount: 22
> deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.86GiB/s
> 2022-01-11 13:31:35.812308: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible
> gpu devices: 0 The thread 0x3ae0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> 2022-01-11 13:33:08.924749: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device
> interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2022-01-11
> 13:33:08.924773: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
> 2022-01-11 13:33:08.924779: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
> 2022-01-11 13:33:08.924942: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created
> TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with
> 4914 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX
> 1660, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5) 2022-01-11
> 13:33:08.926509: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:361] Device mapping:
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name:
> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability:
> 7.5

Specifically, let's say I want just this one line to log:

> 2022-01-11
> 13:33:08.926509: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:361] Device mapping:
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name:
> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability:
> 7.5

Thanks!

Comment: It's also very well possible that the unmanaged code uses the windows function `OutputDebugString()` which is only going to the debugger. I'm not sure this can be intercepted.

Comment: Have you considered redirecting stdout? https://codingcanvas.com/redirecting-standard-error-for-a-net-application/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788279/redirecting-stdin-and-stdout-in-net

Comment: Good point, I am not sure it uses the Windows function because it is cross platform, it can run on Linux and everything. But, I can check the Github source to see if it does. Thanks!

Comment: @PMF "*I'm not sure [OutputDebugString] can be intercepted*" - if it couldn't then tools like [SysInternals DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) would not be able to work.

Comment: @littleadv I have seen code like this in my searching on Google. What I am confused about is most of them use the Process to start a process and then it can capture or redirect the output. I don't start the process. I just reference the library, which is a wrapper for the unmanaged code and them make method calls. I am not sure how to fit the process stuff into this.

Comment: so you need to redirect your own stdout/stderr and not a new process' ones, that's the only difference

Comment: I don't think it's logging to stdout / stderr.  That goes to the bit bucket under Windows.

Comment: I just edited my post for more information. I tried what you suggested @littleadv and it doesn't seem to work. Assuming that it is not actually using STDOUT at this point. I am grabbing a log line from the output window right now so maybe I can look it up in the source to see where it is logging.

Comment: Project > Properties > Debug tab, untick "Enable native code debugging" and you won't see the debug output anymore.  This is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Those tools, as far as I know, intercept the system calls on a very low level. Of course that can be done, but it is probably much more difficult than redirecting standard output or standard error.

Comment: @PMF intercepting OutputDebugString() is not quite as low level as you think: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html. It is just a matter of mapping a memory buffer and syncing with a few kernel events